# Prevent a page break across two different environment

Tags: lists, page-breaking, multicol

I need to tie two different environments, i.e., prevent a page break from happening. I tried `\nopagebreak`, `\nobreak`, `\begin{samepage}-\end{samepage}`, but nothing worked.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item ....
\item týden 
    Pondělí:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \item \[\frac{\frac{1}{a-1}+\frac{2}{a-1}+\frac{3}{a-1}}{\frac{1}{a^{2}-1}}\]
        \vysl{$6(a+1)$ PODM: $a\neq\pm1$}
    \item \[(y^{2}-2)^{3}\] 
        \vysl{$y^{6}-6y^{4}+12y^{2}-8$}
    \end{multicols}
    \item \[A-B=?;A=\{x\in\R;-3\leq x\leq 10\};B=\{x\in\R;-4<x<8\}\]
        \vysl{$A-B=\{x\in\R;8
        \leq x\leq 10\}$}
    \end{enumerate}
```

Page breaks somewhere between word "Pondělí" and environment `multicols`, but I need it together.

Thanks for all answers and excuse my English, I hope everything is understandable.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you looked into the [needspace](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/needspace) package?

Answer (score 2):

You should try the `needspace` package. Since it looks like 5 to 6 lines are occupied by the material that needs to be kept together, you might try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,needspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%% how is the "\vysl" macro defined?

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \dots
\item týden 
    \needspace{6\baselineskip}
    Pondělí:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \item \[\frac{\frac{1}{a-1}+\frac{2}{a-1}+\frac{3}{a-1}}{\frac{1}{a^{2}-1}}\]
        \vysl{$6(a+1)$ PODM: $a\neq\pm1$}
    \item \[(y^{2}-2)^{3}\] 
        \vysl{$y^{6}-6y^{4}+12y^{2}-8$}
    \end{multicols}
    \item \[A-B=?;A=\{x\in\R;-3\leq x\leq 10\};B=\{x\in\R;-4<x<8\}\]
        \vysl{$A-B=\{x\in\R;8
        \leq x\leq 10\}$}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

(I'm afraid I can't post a screenshot as I don't know how the `\vsyl` macro is defined.)